# Fetch gmail thread conversation of my crm contacts only

Tags: gmail-api

Basically am using gmail php api to show gmail inbox for my users. But the main thing is that i only want to show the gmail thread conversations of my crm contacts. For this i pass all the emails of my contacts in the q parameter of gmails threads but this the q parameter works only untill 250 emails after that i got bad request error in response. could anyone please tell is there any limit on the length of q parameter of gmail php api or a better way to handle this situation..

Answer (score 0):

Because of the query length limit, you will most likely have to divide your set of emails into batches that fit within the query limit.

If performance is an issue, you can use a batch request to group the email batches into a single request.  See:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch

Note:  the requests within your batch will still be subject to rate and concurrent request limits.  See:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

Comment: But i want to show latest conversation at top...by this way i cant fetch the latest conversation with all of our leads

Comment: Yes, the Gmail API query mechanism cannot do complex queries.  For your case, it may be best to make a single query per email, sort newest first, limit to the first 1-2 results, and then batch those up using the batch request mechanism.